# Node Js Error: "error Expected catch() or return, promise/catch-or-return" FIREBASE

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy to Firebase functions for my Social Media App. I am creating CRUD functions for user posts etc. but i get error below. Code is attached beneath.

**ERROR**

```
=== Deploying to 'AppName-780db'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint F:\_dev\AppName\functions
> eslint .


F:\_dev\AppName\functions\index.js
  118:7   error  Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
 A 126:11  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
  151:7   error  Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
  159:11  error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 4 problems (4 errors, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USERPC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-13T23_04_10_358Z-debug.log
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
```

I have trimmed and pasted the snippets with errors in question because Stack says i posted mostly code.

**CODE**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("timeline")
        .doc(followerId)
        .collection("timelinePosts")
        .doc(postId)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            doc.ref.update(postUpdated);
          }
        });
===============

admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("timeline")
        .doc(followerId)
        .collection("timelinePosts")
        .doc(postId)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            doc.ref.delete();
          }
```

Comment: I removed mentions of Flutter here, because what you're showing doesn't have anything directly to do with Flutter.  This is JavaScript backend code running in Cloud Functions, which is agnostic to the type of frontend you call it with.  The problem here is with JavaScript eslint warnings.

Comment: @DougStevenson I had seen those posts and they do not work on my code. I have added `return` and `error`  they just add more errors.  I am following a **Udemy** lesson and for the author the code works by in my case it returns those errors. Since i read that these are just warnings is there a way to ignore them in the interim?

Comment: The author is giving you coding advice that doesn't line up with JavaScript best practices, as determined by eslint.  If you restructure the code as described in the duplicates, the errors will go away.

Comment: I deleted the Functions folder reinstalled Node, updated packages and chose No on installing Eslint Everything worked fine and managed to deploy. You suggest that i enable Eslint and try to solve the warnings?

Comment: IMO, if you want to have the highest quality code, enable all warnings, and resolve them all.